# How to show value from SQL Server in Pentaho Report Designer that use nvarchar data type

Tags: sql-server, pentaho, nvarchar

I am new in `Pentaho Report Designer` & `SQL Server`. I have a database using `SQL Server 2000`. I create this query from that database:

```
SELECT CASE     
WHEN STATUS IS NULL THEN 'LAIN-LAIN'
ELSE STATUS
END AS STATUS, 
   CASE
WHEN COUNT(*) IS NULL THEN '0'
ELSE COUNT(*)
END AS BIL
FROM (SELECT D.DAJ_NODAFTAR
          ,(SELECT TOP 1 
                   DAJ_KLASIFIKASI
              FROM BATM112_RKDKLASIFIKASI
             WHERE DAJ_NODAFTAR = D.DAJ_NODAFTAR
             ORDER BY DAJ_TKHDE DESC) STATUS
      FROM BATM112_DES_AMJENTERA AS D
     WHERE D.DAJ_KODKAT = 'VTC') a
GROUP BY STATUS
```

I run this query in `Query Analyzer` and the result come out just like I want:

```
STATUS       BIL
----------------
LAIN-LAIN    10
JK           456
TYG          6
RD           2
JKD          64
RDB          1
```

After that, I try to run this query in `Pentaho Report Designer` but the result I get is like this:

```
STATUS       BIL
----------------
             10
             456
             6
             2
             64
             1
```

For your information, `DAJ_NODAFTAR` and `DAJ_KLASIFIKASI` are using `NVARCHAR` as `Data Type`. After trying to run this query in `Pentaho Report Designer`, I realize that it cannot show value for variable that use `nvarchar` as data type.

Please someone teach me how to fix this? Is there any other way to make `Pentaho Report Designer` show value for `nvarchar data type`?

Answer (score 0):

At last I got the answer myself. I just change a little bit in my query. I change like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN STATUS IS NULL THEN 'LAIN-LAIN'
ELSE STATUS
END AS STATUS, 
   CASE
WHEN COUNT(*) IS NULL THEN '0'
ELSE COUNT(*)
END AS BIL
FROM (SELECT D.DAJ_NODAFTAR
          ,(SELECT TOP 1 
                   CAST( DAJ_KLASIFIKASI AS VARCHAR(25) )
              FROM BATM112_RKDKLASIFIKASI
             WHERE DAJ_NODAFTAR = D.DAJ_NODAFTAR
             ORDER BY DAJ_TKHDE DESC) STATUS
      FROM BATM112_DES_AMJENTERA AS D
     WHERE D.DAJ_KODKAT = 'VTC') a
 GROUP BY STATUS
```

And the result come out perfectly. Just like I want.